# How to drain a baseboard radiator system for a repair? How to refill the system?

Tags: repair, radiator, pipe

I have a leak in the second zone in my baseboard radiator system.  When installing some drywall in the room the previous owners nicked the copper pipe with a drywall screw, and it appears to have rusted through the pipe.  I know I need to replace that section of pipe, but I can't solder the new piece in until the pipe is empty of water.

How can I get all the water out of the system, and when refilling, how do I fill the system back up and get any air out?

Comment: Is the system "sealed" or "vented"? (A vented system has a tank in the attic, a sealed system is kept under pressure.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need to **solder** in the new pipe?

There are pushfit and compression fittings designed for fix leaks.

Assuming the leak is very small you could also use leak stop patty that you just form round the pipe

(Once you move away from solder, you may not need to drain the system if the leak is small enough.)